# PHP/MySQL how can I select a value from a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I select a value from a database that a user just entered it into and then add it to another mysql table all in the same script before the script is finished running.

Comment: What do you mean.. look up mysql and php on Google, there are literally tons of guides on how to do what you mentioned.

Comment: Well within his rights to ask that question, according to the Stack Overflow.

Comment: The FAQ states that it's perfectly acceptable to post any programming question here, regardless of how basic, as long as it's not a matter for protracted discussion and of interest to at least one other person.

Comment: He's within his rights, sure (hence why I haven't touched the question's vote score), but a little more clarity couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for an [insert ... select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for but how do I select from one database and add it to another?

Comment: I tried it from my previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845254/php-mysql-table-problem

Answer (score 1):

Like nash said, you perform a select.

But to get the data from the row that the user just entered, you'll need:

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

Which grabs the last ID inserted (this is assuming you have an increment id column)

So assuming just entered his first and last name in a form, you'd insert his first and last name in the database(which i assume you know how since the title of this question is "SELECT a value from MySQL database"), you can get what he just entered by:

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

If there are no rows on that table yet, then this will return 1. $last_id is now 1 (one).

To select:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = "$last_id"
```

this will grab what the user just inserted....however, this seems pointless as you can use the variables from the form he just filled

Comment: I tried it from my previous question it failed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845254/php-mysql-table-problem

Comment: Are yo saying I'm going to have the call the database agian?

Answer (score 0):

Some tutorial that you may want to look at: (grabbed from google)

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-mysql-tutorial.html

In theory you perform a select, take the data you need and perform an insert.

Comment: that's the question I'm asking my self.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about adding a value that a user just entered into a form, to something, and then putting that into the database, you should do the addition while in PHP. There's no point in going to the database after you've just inserted the value for this purpose.

If I'm misunderstanding something, please elaborate your question and let us know WHY you would want to figure out a just-inserted database value and do an operation on it, rather than trying to do it before you insert in the first place.

Also, if it's a fairly simple modification consider using an UPDATE statement, not a select --> insert.

Comment: I'm trying to get this part of the question that was semi answered to work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845254/php-mysql-table-problem

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP MySQL module, you normally perform a [mysql_select_db()](http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) to switch database.

You can insert your data into tables in different databases by switching between them with that function.

However, you can insert data into any table of any database (which the user has access to) by prefixing the database name to the table like so:

```
INSERT INTO test_db.test_table (`column1`,`column2`) VALUES ('abc',123);
```

You can use that also to insert data from one table into another using:

```
INSERT INTO `db1`.`myTable` (`column1`,`column2`) SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `db2`.`myTable` WHERE `id`= 5
```

The WHERE `id` part should obviously match the id of a row in db2.myTable

Answer (score 0):

If you use [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) you have the inserted data in the object representing the table and in addition you have primary key assigned for the record inside the object.

Con is doctrine is huge database abstraction layer, so if your application is not big doctrine is hammer for mosquito.

Answer (score 0):

what is the structure of your database? The names of your tables, columns?